# Google Play Store showing an app on "All apps" but not on any of the devices

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

It is possible to see where an app is installed on a device on the Google Play Store web. I go to Apps - [My Apps](https://play.google.com/apps), and have a drop-down menu with all the devices. However, there is one particular app which appears when "All apps" is selected, to be installed. But when choosing from the 3 devices listed in the drop-down menu, it does not appear on any of them.

Does this mean the app is installed nowhere? Why is it then shown in "All apps" when on other occasions when uninstalling an app from a device it disappears? Could it be installed on a computer and therefore shown as installed but not visible for the devices? Any way of knowing where the app is installed based on the Google user?

Comment: From my understanding "all my apps" are all apps you had ever installed (thus those you "own" that most were free to buy doesn't matter). Those apps don't have to be installed on any device but you still own it.

Comment: Hi Robert, thing is that I owned far way more apps then the once shown. Like I know of games and others I"owned" which I uninstalled and which do not appera i my apps. But this particular app seems to stay in "my Apps". And i am wondering why or if ot still somewhere installed.

Comment: There's a possibility that it has been installed on other Android devices that are not registered to this Google account *anymore*, e.g. by removing/disconnecting the account from the device. Generally, uninstalling an app shouldn't remove the entry on "My Apps", unless it's also removed from the device's Play Store's "Manage my Apps".